# Find out if Wordpress multisite uses subdirectory or subdomain for new blogs

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, subdirectory

Is there a function to check if a Wordpress multisite install uses the subdirectory or subdomain option when new blogs get created?

I'm using the function [wpmu_create_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog) to create new blogs. 
The Codex explains:

*On subdirectory installs, $domain is the same as the main site's domain, and the path is the subdirectory name (eg 'example.com' and '/blog1/'). On subdomain installs, $domain is the new subdomain + root domain (eg 'blog1.example.com'), and $path is '/'.*

So I would need a way to find out if the multisite is a subdirectory or subdomain install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, we have the very [constant defined in `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Network_Screen):

```
if ( defined( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL' ) ) 
{
    if( SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL )
        echo '<h2>Is: SUBDOMAIN</h2>';
    else
        echo '<h2>Is: SUBDIRECTORY</h2>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `wp_get_sites()` to get information about your blogs. It will return an array containing information about all existing blogs.

Example result from [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites):

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [blog_id] => 1
        [site_id] => 1
        [domain] => example.com
        [path] => /
        [registered] => 2013-11-08 17:56:46
        [last_updated] => 2013-11-08 18:57:19
        [public] => 1
        [archived] => 0
        [mature] => 0
        [spam] => 0
        [deleted] => 0
        [lang_id] => 0
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [blog_id] => 2
        [site_id] => 1
        [domain] => example.com
        [path] => /examplesubsite/
        [registered] => 2013-11-08 18:07:22
        [last_updated] => 2013-11-08 18:13:40
        [public] => 1
        [archived] => 0
        [mature] => 0
        [spam] => 0
        [deleted] => 0
        [lang_id] => 0
    )
)
```

[0] will be your main blog, so I'd ignore this. But by checking the first blog after that you should be able to get the information.

```
$info = wp_get_sites();
if ($info[1]['path'] == "/") {
    // the installation uses subdomains
}
else {
    // the installation uses subdirectorys
}
```

Of course this only works when there is at least one additional blog created, but I couldn't find any other option to check for.

Comment: Thanks. thats already useful (can't vote up because not enough reputation). Although I still wonder if there would be a better solution that would work when no subsites have been created yet.

Comment: `wp_get_sites()` is deprecated. Use `get_sites()`. `$info = get_sites();` Condition: `If($info[1]->path == '/')`